# Daily, MTD, QTD, YTD Sums as of a Specific Date bifurcated by Specific Field in Slicer

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I would like to create a time series analysis with groupings by a column and have the analysis be as of a user selected date, from a slicer, and show daily, mtd, qtd, ytd totals. The values that show up in the daily, mtd, qtd, ytd would only include values up to the date in the slicer. i found this difficult because of dates where there is not a color (grouping), the color drops out of the report and that causes the MTD / QTD / YTD for the aggregate to be missing that value

sample data:

| Date | Amount | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/5/2023 | 50 | red |
| 1/10/2023 | 55 | blue |
| 1/15/2023 | 60 | red |
| 7/1/2023 | 1 | yellow |

if i choose 1/5/23 in my slicer, the matrix visual would show

| Color | Daily | MTD | QTD | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 |

if i choose 1/10/23 in the slicer, the report would show

| Color | Daily | MTD | QTD | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 0 | 50 | 50 | 50 |
| Blue | 55 | 55 | 55 | 55 |

if i choose 1/15/23 in the slicer, the report would show

| Color | Daily | MTD | QTD | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 60 | 110 | 110 | 110 |
| Blue | 0 | 55 | 55 | 55 |

if i choose 7/1/23 in the slicer, the report would show

| Color | Daily | MTD | QTD | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 0 | 0 | 0 | 110 |
| Blue | 0 | 0 | 0 | 55 |
| Yellow | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I have tried writing a DAX to calculate a custom column which shows the MTD, QTD, YTD for the single data table as shown above. it works fine unless you choose a date in which the colors are not all represented but have all occured - for example, choosing 1/10/23 in the slicer causes red to not show up as it doesn't have a record for that date, even though it has a MTD , QTD, YTD which contribute to the aggregate table amount.

I tried creating a separate table for all daily permutations but wasn't sure how to get all  possible permutations of date and color - for example, that table would have

| Date | Amount | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/5/2023 | 50 | Red |
| 1/5/2023 | 0 | blue |
| 1/10/2023 | 55 | blue |
| 1/10/2023 | 0 | Red |
| 1/15/2023 | 60 | Red |
| 1/15/2023 | 0 | Blue |
| 7/1/2023 | 0 | Red |
| 7/1/2023 | 0 | Blue |
| 7/1/2023 | 1 | Yellow |

i have experimented with joining a separate calendar table but don't think i got the syntax right.

this is just sample data, and i plan to use the architecture for many time series data points so would like the layout to be as flexible and adaptable as possible, so i am trying to avoid creating a specific month, quarter, year table of just results.

The problem specifically (i think!) is the lack of continuous data

Comment: Please update your question with [markdown formatted tables](https://tabletomarkdown.com/)

Comment: thank you for the help with that @Sam Nseir. first post. will do that going forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Date table: [Set and use date tables in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-date-tables).

Create a new Calculated Table with the following (as an example):

```
DateTable = SUMMARIZE(
  CALENDARAUTO(),
  [Date],
  "Year", YEAR([Date]),
  "Month", FORMAT([Date], "MMM"),
  "MonthNum", MONTH([Date]),
  "Year-Month", FORMAT([Date], "yyyy-MM"),
  "Quarter", "Q" & QUARTER([Date]),
  "Year-Quarter", FORMAT([Date], "yyyy-\Q") & QUARTER([Date])
)
```

Once created, do the following:

- Select the `Date` column, and change its format as desired.
- Select the `Month` column, and `Sort by column` on `MonthNum`.
- Right-click on the `DateTable` and select `Mark as date table`, and set the `Date column` to `Date`.

Now create a one-to-many relationship from the `DateTable` to your fact/data table.

Now you can create the following measures, where DAX will take care of the [Time intelligence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax) for you.

```
Total Amount = SUM('YourTable'[Amount])

Amount Daily = [Total Amount]

Amount MTD = TOTALMTD([Total Amount], 'DateTable'[Date])

Amount QTD = TOTALQTD([Total Amount], 'DateTable'[Date])

Amount YTD = TOTALYTD([Total Amount], 'DateTable'[Date])
```

Finally, update your date slicer to use the new `DateTable`.

---

**Follow-up**

You could create the following measures:

```
Total Expenses = SUM('YourTable'[expenses])

Net Amount Daily = [Total Amount] + [Total Expenses]

Net Amount MTD = TOTALMTD([Net Amount Daily], 'DateTable'[Date])

Net Amount QTD = TOTALQTD([Net Amount Daily], 'DateTable'[Date])

Net Amount YTD = TOTALYTD([Net Amount Daily], 'DateTable'[Date])
```

Note: If your "expenses" table is separate to your "amount" table, then you will need to do the following:

- Create a one-to-many relationship from the `DateTable` to your "expenses" table.
- Add a new table called "Dim Color" (as an example), with a column of all the distinct values for Color.
- Create a one-to-many relationship from the "Dim Color" table each of the other two "fact tables" (Amount table, Expenses table).
- Lastly, use "Dim Color" table for your matrix/slicers/filters.

Your model should look similar to this:
[image]

Comment: thank you! that is so helpful and perfectly answered my question. thank you. i tried to mark it as the solution but i don't have enough reputation points to do that yet.

Comment: Follow up question: If I have a table with expenses, what is the best way to net them?  
So a table with Color, date, and negative amount ("expenses") I would now like to make a report that just shows the cumulative total of amount + expense in a matrix? Where would that combined measure be stored?

Comment: See **Follow-up** at the bottom of the updated answer above. If all good, feel free to upvote the answer to benefit others.

Comment: Thank you, all good. I am too new to upvote, stackoverflow says i don't have enough reputation points..