# How to reference value from older date in different row?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to look back one year in Date column to bring back the Actual value of that date into Actual PY column. Please help me write a formula in M and DAX. Thank you!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ithB8.png)
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNtSY.png)

This is my unsuccessful attempt using M with a cyclic reference error.

```
let
    Source = tablename
    AddPYColumn = Table.AddColumn(Source, "PY", each 
        let
            CurrentDate = [Date],
            OneYearAgo = Date.AddYears(CurrentDate, -1),
            PYValue = try Table.SelectRows(Source, each [combined] = [combined] and [Date] = OneYearAgo){0}[Actual] otherwise null
        in
            PYValue
    )
in
    AddPYColumn
```

Comment: CALCULATE + SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR()? DATEADD()?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where/why you were getting a cyclic reference error as your sample code above didn't have errors on my end.

What is missing in your code is to save the current `combined` to be later referenced in the `SelectRows`. Example:

```
let
  CurrentDate = [Date],
  CurrentCombined = [combined],
  OneYearAgo = Date.AddYears(CurrentDate, -1),
  PYValue = try Table.SelectRows(Source, each [combined] = CurrentCombined and [Date] = OneYearAgo){0}[Actual] otherwise null
in
  PYValue
```

---

**Time Intelligence with DAX**

The equivalent in DAX for a Calculated Column would look like:

```
PY =
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Actual]),
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Table'[Date]),
    ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[combined])
  )
```

However, usually Measures are used instead of Calculated Columns when it comes to Time Intelligence. A measure for the same would look like:

```
PY = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Actual]),
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Table'[Date])
  )
```

And if you want to unleash full [Time Intelligence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax) capabilities, then you will need a Date table in your data model. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614259/) to get an idea.

With a Date table, you would use its Date column in the DAX Time Intelligence functions. For example:

```
PY = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Actual]),
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Dim Date'[Date])
  )
```